# How to index a collection with documents that contain field with an array of object Id

Tags: mongodb

I have a table like this

```
person = {
    name : String,
    favoriteFoods : [{type:Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref:'Food'}]
}
```

Q1: I would like to do the searching fast when I search for person with particular favourite food.

May I know if it is possible to index the favoriteFoods field and how to do it?

Q2:
Alternatively, I would like to populate the favoriteFoods fields with Food content when I get back the person documents. May I know if there is command to do so?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can index an array field. It's what's called a [multikey index](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-multikey/) but in reality it's basically creating a normal index. Behind the scenes Mongo flattens the array and builds a separate index for each element.

For Q2 the easiest way to "populate" documents in Mongo is by using [$lookup](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) stage while aggregation, like so:

```
db.person.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      name: "tom"
    }
  },
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "foods",
      "localField": "favoriteFoods",
      "foreignField": "_id",
      "as": "favoriteFoods"
    }
  }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/bMHreHprU67)

However if you first fetch the document you can just do a second db call to the other collection to populate your field, this is how `mongoose` does it for example with their [populate](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html) option.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it is neat. 
For some reason, I would like the array field (favoriteFoods) with an auto generated Id and timestamp like (createdAt, and updatedAt), without extra explicit coding when I create them.  And the updatedAt will really do the job when I update the array field without explicit managing it. May I know do you know any ways for that?

Comment: You can still create an index on that, if you go read the docs I linked it's specified there. also using the dot notation you can still use a simple lookup , like so: https://mongoplayground.net/p/ljhGLL8w-Bi